# Android studio include module :app

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, module

I have a android studio project, with default module :app and a module :foo.

If I try to import :app in :foo it does not work for some reason. On gradle sync, I get 3 error messages: "Failed to resolve: project::app".

Basically I'm trying to have a (more or less) standalone module foo, containing tests and I'd like to get some stuff from :app to make my testing easier.

1. Why is this not possible?
2. I basically need classpath from app, is there any way to get them to foo?

#### foo build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':app')
}
```

#### settings.gradle

```
include ':app', ':foo'
```

Comment: Which `settings.gradle` is that?

Comment: That's a settings.gradle from the root of android studio project.